# Disabling IPv6 capability in my network adapters resolved my extremely slow DNS resolution. Why?

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

Obviously not everyone has this issue since IPv6 is enabled by default, so why me? I'm using Google's IPv6 servers. Once I unticked the checkbox for IPv6 in my adapters' properties, pages began loading almost instantly.

How will disabling IPv6 negatively affect my connection? How can I resolve the issue without disabling?

Comment: Does your IP provide you with an IPv6 address? If it doesn't, then you have your explanation: the DNS request could neither reach the DNS servers, nor could you possibly obtain a reply. Any solution which disconnects your IPv6 (you do not have an IPv6 address, you did not correctly configure your networking, and so on...) would fit equally well as an explanation.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm not very technical when it comes to networking, how can I know if my IP does give an IPv6? Running ipconfig has always just shown me IPv4 addresses, if that's any indication.

Comment: There you have it: if you have only seen IPv4 addresses, then you cannot use IPv6 addresses unless you build a special tunnel. Since you do not seem to have done so from what you say, then you do **not** have access to IPv6 addresses. And using Googl IPv6 DNSes means you will wait forever for a reply.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae To resolve this issue, can I delete the Google IPv6 DNS entries from my router and instead obtain IPv6 DNS info from a WAN interface? Or would that achieve nothing?

Comment: That's exactly the right way to proceed.  If you want you can use Google's IPv4 DNS servers, `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 is not widely deployed and/or supported in the US.  If you specify IPv6 DNS servers without actual IPv6 transport, you have to wait for a DNS timeout and subsequent failiover to IPv4 DNS servers *for every DNS query*.  Hence it's "slow".  Just don't specify any IPv6 configuration parameters and you should be back to normal.

And to complicate this, IPv6 is the preferred transport by default to facilitate a "smooth" transition to IPv6...

FWIW, I've been using IPv6 in the US with a tunnel broker for many years... https://tunnelbroker.net/

Comment: What are you talking about? The US has one of the highest rates of IPv6 deployment in the world.

Comment: That's true, I corrected my statement a bit, but I really don't consider less than 25% adoption of IPv6 in the US "widely deployed", that's all I was trying to get across.  So for now, most of the time, the average Joe doesn't get IPv6 transport, so if one configures for and expects it, quiet suffering will happen most of the time.  I'd love to discover IPv6 transport live at Starbucks!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-enable the IPv6 functionality on the adapters so long as you remove the Google IPv6 DNS servers and instead obtain IPv6 DNS info from a WAN interface.